# displaying servlet response in same html page without hiding form

Tags: javascript, java, html, forms, servlets

I have a HTML page that getting two input values like below
      
    
      
         LoginInfo

```
<body> 
    <form method = "post" action = "LoginInfo"> 
        Login Id: <input type = "text" name = "name"/> <br> 
        Password: <input type = "password" name = "password"/> <br> <input type = "submit" value = "Login"/> 
    </form> 

</body>
```

I am passing these two values to the servelt page like below,

```
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/LoginInfo")
 public class LoginInfo extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
String name = request.getParameter("name");
return name;
}
}
```

and the servlet page is returning something, that I want to display in the html page below the form. Now i could able to display the return string but the form is disappears. I want the both in same html page with hiding the form. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

First off why did you put a return value in the doPost method? As it is your code should not be able to compile

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    return name; // why?? it's not needed
}
```

Secondly to pass a value from a Servlet to a Jsp you have to create an attribute, for instance a request attribute like so

```
 String name = request.getParameter("name");
 request.setAttribute("name", name);
```

Then you have to forward the request back to the Jsp with a request dispacther

```
RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher();
disp.forward("nameofthepagewhereyourformis.jsp");
```

Lastly you can retrieve the attribute in your Jsp via expression language. See below

```
<body> 
   <form method = "post" action = "LoginInfo"> 
    Login Id: <input type = "text" name = "name"/> <br> 
    Password: <input type = "password" name = "password"/> <br> <input type = "submit" value = "Login"/> 
   </form> 

   $(name) // attribute set in the servlet. At the bottom of the form as you wanted
</body>
```